# Finding out total PHP usage in MB's

Tags: centos, grep, awk, ps

I'm trying to find out total memory used by all PHP processes on my CentOS server. After some `grepping` and `awking` this is my final command.

```
ps -e | grep php | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pmap | grep total | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/K//' | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/1024}'
```

Now, theoretically this should be working, as I took the total ram output in K, summed it then divided and that's my MB's. Problem is that's returning

```
12493.5
```

That's 12GB! There is no way they are using 12GB as the server only has 4GB.

**EDIT:** According to the manpage of `pmap` the `-x` switch shows extended information.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap

There is a column in this view called Dirty. Is this the right column? When I awk out on the Dirty column I get:

```
1294.1
```

That would make more sense to me. But I don't know if the Dirty column is the right one or not.

Comment: you are counting shared and virtual memory too - i think that is the issue here...

Comment: Any way to tell `pmap` not to count virtual? Or is there another command to get memory usage other than `pmap` that won't display virtual?

Comment: none I'm aware of but it should be possible to get the residential memory from a process. it's up to someone else or google to mention a way to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
ps avx
```

and sum up the amount in the column "RSS"

Comment: "RSS: resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (in kiloBytes). (alias rssize, rsz)."

Comment: Which column is the RSS column? I count 10 columns but no headers.

Comment: on my system it's the 8th column

Comment: That seems to work, it's returning the same as the `pmap` command I tried above with `-x`. Final command is `ps avx | grep php | awk '{print $8}' | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/1024}'`

Comment: great. so both of us learned something today :-D